# Identifying uniform thought to be German?

Tags: germany, military-practices

Does anybody recognize this uniform?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  It will be very helpful if you can [edit] your question to tell us anything that you can about the person pictured in the uniform, even if it is only a suspected person, please?

Answer (score 1):

From the style, I would think it is a Hussar Jacket, or similarly a Ulan Jacket. Maybe this helps: http://www.uniformology.com/RUHL-04.html